# Can larger transactions have a lesser fee per byte than smaller ones and still get equally treated?

Tags: transaction-fees, transaction-weight

Is the term "volume discounting" applicable in bitcoin transactions, meaning can a user pay less satoshi/Byte if a few transactions are bundled into one?

In other words, would a fee for a single bundled transaction be less than the sum of fees for several small-sized (in bytes) transactions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. There is no unit price discount for making larger transactions. Such transactions consume similar resources to multiple transactions which sum to the same size. They consume the same amount of block space, so they will cost the same in transaction fees.

Comment: Perhaps it would be useful in this context to note that while all of the above is true, batching multiple payments into one transaction will result usually result in a smaller transaction, though.